# EzAPI OLE DB Destination

Tags: c#, com, ssis, ezapi

I've searched all over and I now have to ask SO. I'm trying to construct a simple dataflow using EzAPI. It's been anything but easy, but I'm committed to figuring this out. What I can't figure out is how to get the `EzOleDBDestination` working. Here's my complete code

```
var a = new Application();
// using a template since it's impossible to set up an ADO.NET connection to MySQL
//  using EzAPI and potentially even with the raw SSIS API...
var pkg = new EzPackage(a.LoadPackage(@"C:\...\Package.dtsx", null));
pkg.Name = "Star";

var df = new EzDataFlow(pkg);
df.Name = "My DataFlow";

var src = new EzAdoNetSource(df);
src.Name = "Source Database";
src.SqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM enum_institution";
src.AccessMode = AccessMode.AM_SQLCOMMAND;
src.Connection = new EzConnectionManager(pkg, pkg.Connections["SourceDB"]);
src.ReinitializeMetaData();

var derived = new EzDerivedColumn(df);
derived.AttachTo(src);
derived.Name = "Prepare Dimension Attributes";
derived.LinkAllInputsToOutputs();
derived.Expression["SourceNumber"] = "id"; 
derived.Expression["Name"] = "(DT_STR,255,1252)description";

// EDIT: reordered the operation here and I no longer get an error, but 
//  I'm not getting any mappings or any input columns when I open the package in the designer
var dest = new EzOleDbDestination(df);
dest.AttachTo(derived, 0, 0);
dest.Name = "Target Database";
dest.AccessMode = 0;
dest.Table = "[dbo].[DimInstitution]";
dest.Connection = new EzConnectionManager(pkg, pkg.Connections["TargetDB"]);

// this comes from Yahia's link
var destInput = dest.Meta.InputCollection[0];
var destVirInput = destInput.GetVirtualInput();
var destInputCols = destInput.InputColumnCollection;
var destExtCols = destInput.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection;
var sourceColumns = derived.Meta.OutputCollection[0].OutputColumnCollection;

foreach(IDTSOutputColumn100 outputCol in sourceColumns) {
    // Now getting COM Exception here...
    var extCol = destExtCols[outputCol.Name];
    if(extCol != null) {
        // Create an input column from an output col of previous component.
        destVirInput.SetUsageType(outputCol.ID, DTSUsageType.UT_READONLY);
        var inputCol = destInputCols.GetInputColumnByLineageID(outputCol.ID);
        if(inputCol != null) {
            // map the input column with an external metadata column
            dest.Comp.MapInputColumn(destInput.ID, inputCol.ID, extCol.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, anything that involves calls to `ReinitializeMetadata()` results in 0xC0090001, because that method is where the error happens. There's no real documentation to help me, so I have to rely on any gurus here.

I should mention that the source DB is MySQL and the target DB is SQL Server. Building packages like this using the SSIS designer works fine, so I know it's possible.

Feel free to tell me if I'm doing anything else wrong.

EDIT: here's a link to the base package I'm using as a template: http://www.filedropper.com/package_1 . I've redacted the connection details, but any MySQL and SQL Server database will do. The package will read from MySQL (using the MySQL ADO.NET Connector) and write to SQL Server.

The database schema is mostly irrelevant. For testing, just make a table in MySQL that has two columns: id (int) and description (varchar), with id being the primary key. Make equivalent columns in SQL Server. The goal here is simply to copy from one to the other. It may end up being more complex at some point, but I have to get past this hurdle first.

Comment: can you post a link to the package file you are using, and tell more about database schema?

Comment: @avs099 Question has been updated.

Comment: I'll post as an answer if this is it, but reading the code, I believe the reason it's flipping out is the Connection property had not been set nor does it know what the target table is. I remember having issues when I was working with ezapi project doing things out of order. Looking at my code, I also never called ReinitializeMetadata directly. If you snag the source, you'll see the Ez components call it with some regularity. Look at my code for the [destination object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916674/what-is-the-ezapi-equivalent-for-using-an-ole-db-source-command-from-variable)

Comment: @billinkc: the connection property was set and if you looked at the commented out lines, you'd see that I specified the table and access mode, but those were throwing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this now BUT I am rather sure that the following will help you get it working:

- [Calling `ReinitializeMetadata()` causes the component to fetch the table metadata. This should only be called after setting the `AccessMode` and related property.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/api-sample-oledb-source-and-oledb-destination.aspx) You are calling it before setting `AccessMode`...
- [Various samples including advice on debugging problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/samples-for-creating-ssis-packages-programmatically.aspx)
- define the derived column(s) directly in the SQL command instead of using a `EzDerivedColumn`
- try to get it working with 2 SQL Server DBs first, some of the available MySQL ADO.NET provider have some shortcomings under some circumstances

UPDATE - as per comments some more information on debugging this and a link to a complete end-to-end sample with source:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/08/03/looking-up-ssis-hresult-comexception-errorcode.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/08/03/debugging-a-comexception-during-package-generation.aspx
- [Complete working sample with source](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17647)

Comment: I'll try the first few things in a bit, but I don't think your last point is valid. I'm able to do this kind of thing with packages that I build by hand in the designer (MySQL -> SQL Server, including the derived column).

Comment: @siride as I wrote it depends on which MySQL provider you use... some are less quirky than others... if you are using a stable one then that is a good thing :-)

Comment: So I tried reordering things a bit and if I set the Table and AccessMode before setting the connection, I get through without an error. The problem is that there are no mappings when I open up the destination in the SSIS designer. Using the examples from your links, I get the COM exception again because the destination doesn't think it has any input columns (see my updated code).

Comment: still get the same error...as would be expected. The problem is not in the derived column.

Comment: what I'm seeing here is that EzAPI is not up to the task and that if I have any hope of making this work, I have to use the raw API.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as it's the closest to what I'd need if I were to actually continue this project. It appears that EzAPI is not usable in all but the simplest scenarios and that building packages programmatically is even more tedious than doing it in BIDS. Thank you for your answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact same issue and been able to resolve it with a lot of experimentation. In short you must set the connection for both the source and destination, and then call the attachTo after both connections are set. You must call attachTo for every component.

I've written a blog about [starting with an SSIS package as a template, and then manipulating it programmatically to produce a set of new packages](http://www.dimodelo.com/blog/2015/ezapi-existing-package-template/).

The article explains the issue more.